# CakePHP Plugin Model Associations Not Working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

The Scenario: I have a CakePHP App, With a Plugin called Fruit. The Fruit Plugin contains a route to the TagsController.php with an Action of index which points to index.ctp

The Tags Model has one association. user_id

The Problem: Even with me adding a joins option to the Model->find('all'... the ['User'] index is undefined. I am not sure what to do, here is my code....

TagsController

```
public function index($ajax = false) {
    $this->Tag->recursive = 2;
    $tags = $this->Tag->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')), 'joins'=>array(
    array(
         'table'=>'users',
         'alias'=>'User',             
         'conditions'=>array(
              'User.id=Tag.user_id'
         )
    ),
    )));

    print_r($tags);

    $this->set('tags', $this->paginate());

    if($ajax == 'ajax')
    {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }
}
```

Tags Model

```
App::uses('FruitAppModel', 'Fruit.Model');
class Tag extends FruitAppModel {

public $name = 'Tag';
public $uses = array('User');
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(

        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

User Model

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {

public $name = 'User';
public $displayField = 'username';

public $hasMany = array(        
    'Tag' => array(
        'className' => 'Fruit.Tag',
        'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),

);
```

I have been stuck on this problem for several hours now, so any fresh ideas on what I can try are greatly appreciated. I have combed through stackoverflow pretty good and I am just going in circles, I need a fresh pair of eyes on this. Any ideas at all would be awesome.

Thank you!

- Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have tried a lot and made it more complicated, try this code it will give you desired output.

in user model:

```
public $hasMany = array(        
'Tag' => array(
    'className' => 'Fruit.Tag',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'dependent' => false,
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => '',
    'limit' => '',
    'offset' => '',
    'exclusive' => '',
    'finderQuery' => '',
    'counterQuery' => ''
),
```

in controller:--

```
$this->Tag->recursive = 1;

 $this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Tag.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
);
$data = $this->paginate('Tag');
pr($data);
$this->set(compact('data'));
```

Comment: What about doing the contrary? If I want to relate a Model in the Plugin to belongs to a "core" model ?